# How to toggle the visibility of a responsive navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, navbar

I'm trying to make a responsive navigation bar, which is visible, if I click a button (icon) and is not visible if I click this button again. I've also tried it with .addEventListener(click, ...), but I just can't get it done. (so this would be my preferred way) I  think it's a pretty basic question, but I have't found a way to solve it. Here's what I got:

**Snippet:**

```js
function toggleNav() {
  let open = false;
  if (open == false) {
    navUl = document.getElementById("navUl");
    navUl.style.display = "block";
    open = true;
  }

  if (open == true) {
    navUl = document.getElementById("navUl");
    navUl.style.display = "none";
    open = false;
  }
}
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  /* nav bar */
  #bars {
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul {
    display: none;
  }
  /* heading */
  #opener h1,
  #audioPlayer h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <style>
    body {
      background: url(img/acoustic-gtr.jpg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <title>Musik von Paul</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <a href="index.html"><img src="img/gtr-icon.png" alt="gtr-icon"></a>
    <i class="fa fa-bars" id="bars" onclick="toggleNav()"></i>
    <ul id="navUl">
      <li>CDs
        <ul>
          <li><a href="cd1-akustik.html">1. CD: Akustik Gitarre</a></li>
          <li><a href="cd2-2019.html">2. CD: 2019</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>E-Gitarre
        <ul>
          <li><a href="rock-metal.html">Rock & Metal</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      <li>Akustik Gitarre
        <ul>
          <li><a href="klassik.html">Klassik</a></li>
          <li><a href="fingerstyle.html">Fingerstyle</a></li>
          <li><a href="sonstiges.html">Sonstiges</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <section id="opener">
    <h1>Gitarrenaufnahmen von Paul</h1>
    <br>
    <a href="cd1-akustik.html">CD 1: Aufnahmen Akustik Gitarre</a>
    <a href="cd2-2019.html">CD 2: Aufnahmen von 2019</a>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Variable declaration issue so only it is not working in your code. I have slightly modified your code. Hope this help you.

```
let open = false;    
function toggleNav(){
  if(open==false){
      navUl = document.getElementById("navUl");
      navUl.style.display="block";
      open = true;
  }else{
        navUl = document.getElementById("navUl");
        navUl.style.display="none";
        open = false; 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element is visible( i.e display=='block' ),the element can be hidden.If it is hidden( i.e display=='none' ),the element can be shown. window.getComputedStyle() will get the css of the particular element.

```
function toggleNav(){
   let navUl = document.getElementById("navUl");
   // If the element is visible, hide it
   if (window.getComputedStyle(navUl).display === 'block') {
       navUl.style.display = 'none';
   }else{
       navUl.style.display = 'block';//if element is not visible then display
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of typos in your code

> `open = false` should be declare as global variable, you are assigning
>   `open` as `false` every time you are invoking `toggleNav()` function.
>
> You can directly check if variable is truthy, simply as `if (open)`
>   instead of `if (open == true)`
>
> Instead of assigning `true` or `false` in if/else condition, you can
>   directly assign opposite of what it is not currently. like `open = !open` so if open is false then it will become true and vice-versa

**Final Code will be like**

```
let open = false;
function toggleNav() {
  open = !open;
  if(open){
    navUl = document.getElementById("navUl");
    navUl.style.display="none";        
  } else {
    navUl = document.getElementById("navUl");
    navUl.style.display="block";

  }
}
```